# Flutter in android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I created a new flutter project in android studio, but in the new version, I don't know where to find the main dart tab.

[reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dv5K6.png)

Comment: once check in the lib folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find out main.dart in lib folder

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to open the lib folder inside the lib folder you will get your main. dart file.
[image]